# Is there an equivalent way to use InheritableThreadLocal in Quarkus?

Tags: java, quarkus

I get an error when I try to compile my application in native mode. The problem seems to be this definition of a InheritableThreadLocal variable:

```
class utilityClass {
  ....
  public static InheritableThreadLocal<Locale> requestLocale = new InheritableThreadLocal<>();
  ...
}

@Path("/service")
public class ServiceResource {

  @GET
  @Path ("/print")
  public Response print() {
    .....
    SmeupFormatUtility.requestLocale.set(locale);
    .....
  }
}
```

*Error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved field during parsing: requestLocale. To diagnose the issue you can use the --allow-incomplete-classpath option. The missing field is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.
Detailed message:
Trace:
at parsing Smeup.smeui.uig53.service.ServiceResource.print(ServiceResource.java:187)
....*

Why I can't use InheritableThreadLocal?
Is there an equivalent way to do it in Quarkus?